# Reaction to first emergence

Tags: society, politics, super-powers, military, conflict

I’m writing a story in which the beginning of superheroes arises when four people with vendettas commit extreme acts of violence  using elemental abilities against a few countries.

Powers are as follows: -

1. Castaway: As long he is covered in water  either by being physically covered in water or his clothes are wet with water he gains in invulnerability and super-strength along with the ability to cause agitation, fear, paranoia and schizophrenia in anyone in his immediate vicinity lasts for several hours after castaway Initiated the effect.  Although if the water dries completely he loses his  Super strength and invincibility. So most of his body must be covered in water.
2. Zero point:  Zeno of Clea’s. Paradox of motion  selective invincibly when she is in motion all things in her immediate vicinity slowing to a halt and can’t reach her. So if the bullet was fired at her it would not hit her it would look like it stopped in front of her.  However it is unable to protect against fire And  concussive blasts not to mention poison however energy attacks does not work Her entire body does not have to be in full motion for the effect, it can just be body part of her body.
3. Stormfront: Can create an area of effect about 47.34 mi² in size And produce any natural weather phenomenon at any size or scale  from semi-accurate lightning blast to  Extreme and sudden heat. But must stay within this radius for the effect to be maintained and is immune to the effects of the weather phenomenon. It can only be used at full affect for upwards of an hour and takes about another hour to recharge.
4. Exchange:  Can reverse the entropy of anything she comes into contact However the effect is temporary depending on how large the object is and how orderly it is She could freeze the Atlantic ocean  but it only stays frozen for maybe two seconds  smaller scale uses of this power more effective

How would a team with this power set and military training Be seen In a world where superpowers have just emerged

Comment: This question is underdefined. More details are required. Super powers can range from Dr. Manhattan, whom only one which is an unstoppable global threat, to someone who can change their hair colour at will.

Comment: Thank You for the advice

Comment: I think the hair color one could be a global threat too under the right circumstances.  Like really crazy colors, all the time!

Comment: @Willk A menace to humanity's sensibilities they would be.

Comment: Title says "Four" but you list 3. Is the fourth super power being "one-that-cannot-be-named"?

Comment: Planetary was a global set in their own comic, but they had the writers on their side. Their powers: Mr. Snow - cold and being a bastard of an old man; Jakarta - strong; The Drummer - control and sensing of information; one other with probability powers (and he wasn't there until the last issue). The antagonists were the Four (a version of the Fantastic Four). The two groups were a credible threat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> any natural weather phenomenon

> full affect for upwards of an hour and takes about another hour to recharge

This is a city destroyer.

- Wait till nightfall.
- 1 hour of heavy snow can give [12 inches (30cm)](https://weather.com/science/weather-explainers/news/monthly-seasonal-daily-snowfall-records-united-states#:%7E:text=Most%20Snow%20Measured%20in%20One%20Hour%3A%2012%20Inches&text=Burt%20compiled%20a%20list%20of,2%2C%201966.).
- An hour to recharge.
- Repeat until all drainage channels are saturated with snow, and the city is in a "bowl" shaped snow structure.
- Sudden hot wave to create a thin layer of ice over the top of the snow.
- Now move on to rain.
- 1 hour rain maximum is [32cm](https://www.wunderground.com/blog/weatherhistorian/what-is-the-most-rain-to-ever-fall-in-one-minute-or-one-hour.html). Over 96.6 square km, that's 3.3 x $10^{10}$ litres.
- Then keep repeating massive storm and downpour until everyone in the city drowns. You can walk around the edges topping up the snow barriers, and the thick stormclouds dumping water every other hour will actually strengthen your barriers (freeze / thawing them into a strong ice covering).

If your not content with killing everyone, and you want to destroy everything, you can also alternate heatwaves (50 degreee C) with cold waves (-40 degree C), with an hour between to recharge. This will freeze and thaw everything, any microscopic cracks in buildings will expand as the water in them freezes, and then thaws, letting more water in. You should be able to level a partially submerged city in a week using this technique.

There'll be lots of refugees and bodys for you to mask your presence - nobody will be suspicious of a person stuck in that hell because there'll be millions stuck there with you.

Answer (score 5):

Contrary to popular belief, superpowers aren't what makes a villain (or other powered individual) dangerous. **It's character, skills, and smarts that make an individual dangerous.**

For example, a guy with a gun can be a global threat if they go around assassinating world leaders; they just need to be smart enough to avoid capture and plan successful hits. That doesn't require superhuman powers, just a sharp mind, attention to details, money, etc. If they're clever, ruthless, and a bit lucky, they could probably kill enough important people to cause significant damages on a global stage before they're caught, and if they're *very* clever they might just be able to tip off larger conflicts Archduke-style by assassinating the right people.

On the other hand, even a powerful powered individual can be easily taken out if they're stupid. Say Stormfront stands in the middle of Times Square, cackling madly as he calls down a thunderstorm. A nearby taxi driver draws the obvious conclusion and runs him over with his taxi. Stormfront dies, the end, not a threat.

Similarly, a dripping wet Castaway is facing a SWAT team, acting as a bullet sponge. In between the mental effects, one of the SWAT members decides to throw an incendiary grenade at Castaway. It explodes, burns, some of Castaway's wet clothing dries, and he dies to a sniper's bullet seconds later. Again, no global threat.

The only real ways to be a global threat are:

- Be simply ridiculously powerful, approaching god-like (think Superman or Flash at his most fastest)
- Be able to create a device, creature, virus, etc or anything capable of exponential growth (think grey goo or Ultron/Ironman building drones and drone factories)
- Be highly intelligent (think masterminds, inventor geniuses, powerful AI's, superpowered individuals capable of min-maxing/munchkining their powers, etc)

Comment: In the national security community, "*character, skills, and smarts*" (I like those) are framed as 'capability' and 'intent'.

Answer (score 3):

## Second-Tier Supervillains

The only character who seems like much of a threat at all is Castaway.

Zero Point might well suffocate if Zeno's Paradox applies globally, as diffusion would also stop and oxygen could never reach her when she's moving.  Aside from that, all she's got is selective invulnerability, and to a subset of weapons, at that.  (Directed energy weapons could blind or kill her, flamethrowers would work just fine, etc.)  None of that makes her much of a threat.  If she were also a trained assassin, she might cause some havoc, but not much more than any non-superpowered trained assassin.

Stormfront would do substantially less damage than climate change, and may as well be hanging a neon sign saying "come and get me" whenever he actually uses his ability.  If he can convince lightning to strike out of a clear blue sky and hit targets it otherwise wouldn't, it might be a different story, likewise instantly conjuring tornadoes would be effective.  But dialling up a one-hour hurricane does not a global threat make, and his lack of invulnerability means that the instant he was truly deemed a threat, he'd also *stop* being a threat.

Castaway shows some promise, but his threat level is dependent on what "immediate vicinity" means, and the duration of the induced effect.  If he permanently renders those around him schizophrenic or paranoid, then all he'd need to be is a damp but innocuous disguise artist.  Getting near important people could have a powerfully destabilizing effect.  The super strength and invulnerability would just be getaway assists should he be found out.  If he can do it from somewhere in the same city block, that would definitely have the world looking for him.

So one of the three could be wildly more dangerous than the other two, but in all three cases, "global" seems unlikely.

Answer (score 3):

I'd say they would be a minor annoyance, as there are only 4 of them and their powers are limited in size. The world is a big place, and these Supervillains can only attack at most 4 places at a time. So most of the world can ignore the villains for most of the time. Also unless their invulnerable to all damage all the time a smart opponent waits until they are asleep and kills them with a supersonic cruise missile before they even realize they need to active their powers to defend themselves (or more subtly, poison their food).